# Generating reports while implementing GoAccess: Is it done correctly?

Tags: aws, wordpress

Trying to implement [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) to my WordPress sites that are hosted on AWS Lightsail (Plesk Ubuntu instance). [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-goaccess-web-log-analyzer-on-ubuntu-20-04) is the tutorial by DigitalOcean I am following:

Before transferring the HTML file from remote to local machine, I need to confirm if the file itself created correctly.

On running this command:

```
sudo goaccess /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

all statistics such as unique visitors showing 0.

[image]

There are currently 3 WordPress sites live on this instance of Lightsail.

[image]

Also, will the statistics be of 3 websites together?